# Recommended way to organize JSF big application on daily builds

Tags: version-control, web-applications, jsf, continuous-integration, dailybuilds

We are working in a big team, building a web application in JSF, where each developer develops new task. For example: User Management, Security, System Parameters etc.

We need to create a daily task to build the WAR from the SVN.

We know how to use daily builder, SVN etc.

Our question is how to save it per module? What is the recommended way to build by packages web application as JSF where it's build on MVC module and the pages are part of the bean? Should we use many WARs/Packages?

I need to save it per module, since some days there could errors in one module that shouldn't be uploaded with the rest of the modules. (I know how to compile and find decide if to upload it or not).

Answer (score 2):

You could use "work branch(es)" (or "module branches") in which the development of a module occur. The trunk would contain everything, developers working on a given "module branch" would merge from trunk to work every day but publish to trunk only once work fully done (done includes tests are passing). Something *like* this (picture from [Version Control for Multiple Agile Teams](http://www.infoq.com/articles/agile-version-control)):

[image]

The above picture illustrates a "work branches" per team approach but one could imagine using a finer grained approach and use work branches per modules. The principles are similar.

Then you put the trunk and all the "work branches" under continuous integration.

Comment: The problem is that developers ALWAYS think that their job is finished. I don't have problems with new modules, I have problems with past working modules, that a user by mistake influenced its working functionality by changing common code for instance.

Comment: @Odelya I see. But I don't know how you could handle this except by running non regression tests (e.g. with selenium) on the whole.

Comment: @Pascal this is why I posted this question to StackOverFlow :)

Comment: @Odelya My point was that the only way to check for regressions is to have tests :)

Comment: @Pascal: Could you edit and add more appropriate tags to this particular question? This is at least not JSF related, but I'm unsure which agile specific tags are the best fit :)

Comment: @BalusC I'm not fully satisfied but I did my best (and kept the JSF tag has it seems relevant for the OP even if I agree that there is nothing JSF specific).

Comment: Well it's important to me that it's a web application with MVC architecture

Comment: @Odelya If you think my changes are not appropriate, feel free to reverse. Personally, I think they might help to attract more people.